# Does SharePoint 2019 support column formatting with customRowAction?

Tags: 2019, column-formatting

Testing column formatting on SharePoint 2019 and even a simple json containing customRowAction does not work. It works fine on SharePoint Online.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "button",
    "txtContent": "@currentField",
    "customRowAction": {
      "action": "defaultClick"
    }
}
```

Question: how can I use the customRowAction property on SharePoint 2019?
tx

Comment: Try using this schema for SP 2019 `"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v1/column-formatting.schema.json"`. let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hi Ganesh,
Yes, this does work!  thank you

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use below schema for SharePoint 2019:

```
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v1/column-formatting.schema.json"
```

SharePoint 2019 supports `v1` while SharePoint online supports `v2` schema.

> To format columns in SharePoint 2019 or SharePoint Server Subscription Edition before the Version 22H2 feature update, please use `https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v1/column-formatting.schema.json` as the schema.

**Documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)